# Is the tab bar generally accessible from subpages on iOS?

Tags: navigation, ios, tab-bar, bottom-navigation

The answer at [this StackOverflow question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/115417/should-the-tab-bar-be-accessible-on-sub-pages-in-a-mobile-app) clearly explains that the Material Design guidelines recommend showing the bottom navigation (or [tab bar](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/), as iOS calls it) on subpages.

Is the same practice recommended on iOS (or at least the norm, if there are no official guidelines)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the same with iOS and the tab bar should be visible everywhere.

> Don't hide a tab bar when people navigate to different areas in your app. A tab bar enables global navigation for your app, so it should remain visible everywhere.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/))